# Concat Order-By string in sql dynamically

Tags: c#, sybase, sqlanywhere

i try to change my wpf grid that way, that sorting in the grid will generate a new sql-statement, which should be executed.

A simple way is, to surround my statement with an subselect and append the order-by at the end, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CustomerTable) as _orderBy Order By CustomerNr
```

Does anyone know a better solution for this problem, because creating subselections should not be the best way.

My idea was, to detect if there is an existing order-by and than append the additional columns... But i could not find a very stable way...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i solved my problem like this:

1. I extemded my SQL-Code with my own tag, so that the order-by looks like this:

   > [ORDER-BY]
   >   order by myColumn asc
   >   [/ORDER-BY]
2. if there is no [ORDER-BY] in the sql-code, i use my sold technique:

   > SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM CustomerTable) as _orderBy Order By
   >   CustomerNr
3. If there is an [ORDER-BY], i remove every thing between: [ORDER-BY] and [/ORDER-BY] and create my own order by statement:

   > SELECT * FROM CustomerTable [ORDER-BY] order by CustomerNr desc [/ORDER-BY]

   will be

   > SELECT * FROM CustomerTable order by customerName, customerLastName

Maybe this help some one else.